# Add help_text only for a few fields. Django

Tags: python, django

I have registration form and I want to output help text only for password field. How can I do it?

I want to do something like this in html

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    if field.name == password:
        {{ field.help_text }}
        
{% endfor %}
```

My code:

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm, UsernameField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label="Email")
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email")
        field_classes = {'username': UsernameField, 'email': forms.EmailField}
```

**views.py**

```
class RegisterFormView(FormView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    success_url = "/login/"
    template_name = "blog/register.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Создаём пользователя, если данные в форму были введены корректно.
        form.save()
        # Вызываем метод базового класса
        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**register.html**

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <!-- Username -->
                        <label class="control-label"  for="username">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                        {{ field }}
                        <p>{{ field.help_text }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `field.name` or **[`field.html_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)** equals `password` in the loop

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {{ field }}
    {% if field.name == "password" %}
       {{ field.help_text }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it.

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {{ field }}
    {% if field.name == 'password1' %}
        {{ field.help_text }}
    {% endif %}
    {% if field.name == 'password2' %}
        {{ field.help_text }}
    {% endif %}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```